# Set font using stylesheet for QComboBox with QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qlistview

I have QComboBox and a stylesheet that sets the font size for QComboBox. Previously i added items to QComboBox using 'addItem', but due to performance issue i am using Model view model for my QComboBox

```
QStandardItem modelItem = new QStandardItem;
modelItem->setText("TEST");
QStandardItemModel model = new QStandardItemModel;
model->appendRow(modelItem);
QListView listView = new QListView;

comboBox->setView(listView);
comboBox->setModel(model);
```

This is roughly how my code looks like. How do i use stylesheet to increase the font size in the list when i click on my combo box? My previous stylesheet works okay, until i motified my code to use QStandardItemModel and QListView.

Comment: just append this line: `comboBox->setStyleSheet("QListView { font: 20pt; }");`

Answer (score 1):

Customize your own `QStandardItem` and make your model return the desired font for `Qt::FontRole`:

```
QVariant MyCustomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
     if (role == Qt::FontRole) {
         // Custom your font
         QFont font;
         font.setBold(true);
         return font;
     } else if (role == Qt::ForegroundRole) {
         return QColor(Qt::red); // QBrush color
     } else {
         [..]
     }
}
```

Comment: `modelItem->setData(myFont, Qt::FontRole)` is enough in this case.